# Cannot create Data-Driven subscriptions SSRS (rsHasUserProfileDependencies)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report (with parameters) that uses two subreports and pass parameters to them.

I want to create a data-driven subscription for the report. But I still get a "yellow alert" on the "create data-driven subscription" menu.

-I have stored credentials on my Data Source (and other reports use the same Data Source and can be data-driven)

-The report has 2 date parameters and a string
   parameter used in the query

-The report doesn' t have a linked report

-I am not using anything related to the !User object like userid or
   language...

what can be still causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

IT looks like I solved my own question.
Error message is quite misleading, it tells you about parameters, but have a look to your report variables as well...

I had mistakenly left an empty report variable, removing it solved the problem..

Comment: THANK YOU!
I've looked at so many threads about this and all the same thing... credentials and User! references.

This is the only answer that mentions report variables. I had a forgotten, unused one on the report, removing it solved the issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Data-Driven Subscriptions are not available in the Standard Edition of SQL Server.  Upgrading to Enterprise edition (with new licence key) solved the issue.